# javascript convert string in array format back to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a javascript function that gives me a (var) string in array format like tempString. it's a combined string that looks like an array.
I'm trying to get the elements in there like tempString2. for example get "test" when alert('tempString[0]').
anyone know what i'm missing here? thanks

```
function afunction() {

var tempString = '["test"' + ', "test2"]';
var tempString2 = ["test", "test2"];

console.log(tempString[0]); // output not 'test'
console.log(tempString2[0]); // output test

}
```

Comment: When I run your example I get "[" printed both times - never do I get "test" printed out.

Comment: Output is neither of those. Please provide code that actually demonstrates the problem. Also the example in your paragraph is not consistent. Output would not be `"test"`.

Comment: added an extra set of ' ' on tempString2. removed now. try again. thanks

Comment: Just because you make a string _look_ like an array does not mean it is an array.

Comment: It means, if you're lucky, you've made a javascript array into a JSON string of an array. Simply convert it BACK.

Comment: got it working with json.parse(); danke !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tempString` is going to be treated as string so if you access the index you will get first char of that string.

You can use `JSON.parse` to parse it to object and it will work.

```js
function afunction() {

var tempString = '["test"' + ', "test2"]';
var tempString2 = '["test", "test2"]';
var t=JSON.parse(tempString )
console.log(t)
console.log(t[0]); // output not 'test'
console.log(tempString2[0]); // output test

}
afunction()
```

Comment: trying to get tempString[0], not tempString2[0]. thanks

Comment: @Void once its converted you should be able to access it as actual array...check t variable that holds the actual array after parsing..it doesn't matter it should work with both of your string variables

Comment: you are correct thanks. i parsed the original string and everything worked like pan cakes <3

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
function afunction() {

var tempString = '["test"' + ', "test2"]';
var tempString2 = '["test", "test2"]';

console.log(JSON.parse(tempString)[0]); // output not 'test'
console.log(JSON.parse(tempString2)[0]); // output test

}

afunction()
```